# Электронная библиотека Колибри при запуске выдает следующую ошибку. Что делать?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Электронная библиотека Колибри при запуске выдает следующую ошибку. Что делать?  >_<

Comment: Колибри или Calibre?

Comment: Calibre.///////

Comment: Установите calibre и все её конфиги в папку с с именем из ascii диапазона (без русских букв). Если ошибка после обновления, то перегрузитесь. Полезно проверить что антивирус не пытается global.py одновременно с calibre дёргать.